# Deserialize Datasets per SQL Command

Tags: sql, db2

how do i deserialize Datasets per SQL?

example Source Table:

```
    UserID | Name | Email1 | Email2 | Email3 
    ----------------------------------------------------- 
    1   MaxMan   max.man@example1.com   max.man@example2.com 
    2   MaxGirl  max.girl@example2.com
```

example Out Table:

```
    ID | Name | Email 
    ----------------------------- 
    1    MaxMan   max.man@example1.com
    2    MaxMan   max.man@example2.com
    3    MaxGirl  max.girl@exmaple2.com
```

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24367069/how-to-transform-comma-separated-column-into-multiples-rows-in-db2

Comment: yeah sorry, it's the same request in common.

Comment: no it's not exact the same, .. i have an email entry PER column.. in your link, there are comma separated entrys (in one column)

Comment: i found one Solution by that link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13718184/combine-two-sql-queries-into-one-query?rq=1 .. Try to load the table 3 Times and "union all" it for each Email.. example: SELECT Name, Email1 FROM SourceTable UNION ALL SELECT Name, Email2 FROM SourceTable UNION ALL SELECT Name, Email3 FROM SourceTable ..